# How to add a class when there's no sidebar?

Tags: sidebar

I would like to add a class to a page template's body if the sidebar is not defined. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have multiple templates for your different pages? Is there a 'sidebar' template, and a 'no-sidebar' template? You are getting answers all along the same lines but say these don't work for you so please try to clarify the question.

Comment: No i have only a page.php with sidebar and about 5 pages without sidebar and unique design. I know i can ceeate templates for pages and i can select it from a select menu when i create the page but created files with name page-(pagename).php is it a template too?

Comment: "page-(pagename).php" would be a template too, sure. @Norcross is getting at the point I was fishing for. If you have templates for these different pages, you are making this much more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using an actual page template (as selected in the dropdown panel in the admin area) then using is_page_template('file-name.php') in the body_class function will do it.

then, the CSS would be body.class-name #content would apply to only that template area.

Comment: Yes its true but can is there a way to do that automatically? If get_sidebar exist => addclass has-sidebar

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t know the names of the sidebars you can use `wp_get_sidebars_widgets()`:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpse_77719_sidebar_body_class' );

function wpse_77719_sidebar_body_class( $classes )
{
    $classes[] = wp_get_sidebars_widgets() ? 'has-sidebar' : 'no-sidebar';
    return $classes;
}
```

If you know the names use `is_active_sidebar()` in that function like @s_ha_dum suggested.

Comment: I need something like the twentyeleven theme. I can create pages with sidebar, and without sidebar. If no sidebar added the template adds a "singular" class to the body. Thank you!

Comment: This code should work like that: if no sidebar has been defined a class `.no-sidebar` will be added.

Comment: I removed get_sidebar(); from the template file, but your code adds has-sidebar every time.

Comment: `get_sidebar()` happens long after `body_class()` has been called. Your `sidebar.php` should not create any HTML if there are no sidebars, then it will work.

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand csn you explain please?

Answer (score 1):

With php we can have this with ob_start() and ob_get_clean() but it is kinda hacky.

Better to use javascript:

```
if (!document.contains(document.getElementById('secondary'))) {
    document.body.classList.add('no-sidebar');
}
```

> where `secondary` is your sidebar ID

Comment: Using javascript for this is the ultimate in hacky.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need [`is_active_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_sidebar).

```
if (!is_active_sidebar('sidebar-name')) $class = 'no-sidebar';
```

Or possibly [`is_dynamic_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_dynamic_sidebar).

Comment: I mean if the get_sidebar() added to the template. I have pages with sidebar, but I have pages with custom template where get_sidebar() is not defined. (page-[page-name].php) If sidebar not added the left_content need to be 1000px, if added 800 px for left and 200 for right(sidebar field) content.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that. I'll edit the answer with that clarification in mind.

Comment: Well... Toscho thinks his code will do that. Does it not?

Comment: So what's the best way? For example I have Support, FAQ, Contact page where I need sidebar and I have few pages where I don't need. Every pages is unique, with unique design and functions.